# Laravel Mix Not Compiling Tailwind CSS

Tags: laravel

I just created a new project with Laravel and Sail. I am noticing that some Tailwind css classes are not loading when I run "sail npm run dev". For example, an element that had the utility "py-5" was not loading. So, I decided to try compiling with Laravel Mix again and it finally worked. Same happened when working with Tailwind css column classes. When I run Mix it always shows it compiled successfully.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are run previously this command? `sail npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest`

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably results because you want to build tailwindcss once in the container but it is not configured / installed there. Locally it seems to work for you already. Therefore, you should go through the following steps.

Make sure that you are already install tailwind and other dependency via: `sail npm install`.

Check always if you have postcss anbd autoprefixer installed via sail: `sail npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest`.

Then check your webpack.mix.js file. It have to look like:

```js
mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
    .postCss("resources/css/app.css", "public/css", [
     require("tailwindcss"),
    ]);
```

Add to your css file this three lines:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Then run `sail npm run dev`.

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind has a config option (tailwind.config.js) in what files it will look for the classes used, make sure all the files you use the tailwind class in are part of the `content` option.

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  content: [
    './storage/framework/views/*.php',
    './resources/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/**/*.js',
  ],
  ...
}
```